# Change value of dropdownlist with vb net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change a value of my code through a sql server query using vb net, I intend to do the following: When the user selects an item of value 3 in the dropdownlist I change this value to 31, returning another item from my DB and not item 3

Code :

```
Sql = " select "
Sql += " cod_distrito, no_distrito "
Sql += " from tb_distrito "
Sql += " where "
Sql += " cod_distrito<>0  and cod_distrito <= 25"

            Sql += " order by no_distrito "
Cmd.CommandText = Sql
dt.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader)
cod_distrito.DataSource = dt
cod_distrito.DataBind()
cod_distrito.Items.Insert(0, "Selecione uma Gerência Regional")
cod_distrito.SelectedValue = Seg.usuario.cod_Distrito
'cod_distrito.Enabled = True

'Above you can see where the dropdownlist is consulted
```

Comment: No, I cannot see above where the dropdownlist is consulted.

Comment: @GSerg look again pls

Comment: If the user selects an item of value 2, what should it be changed to? Is there a general rule?

Comment: You know VB.Net has multiline string literals now, right?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Isn't , it's only for the value 3 , i wanna change that value for 31

Comment: Joel , can you explain  ?

Comment: You don't need all those `Sql +=` anymore. You can just say `Sql = "` and not close the literal until several lines later.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i got it , i'm new with VB

Comment: @Magami Even if you were old with it, this has only been possible for the last 4 years of so of VB's 40 year history.

Comment: I think it's a little unclear what exactly your asking.  I'm assuming cod_distrito is the combo your trying to set.  So what is Seg.usuario.cod_Distrito?  Where does that come from?  Please review the help on asking question, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try explaining the actual problem. If you want to change a value to 31, go ahead and do it. If you want to query a database, go ahead and do it. If you want us to help with a problem, explain the actual problem. An actual explanation would describe what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it, what happens when you try and EXACTLY where and how that doesn't meet your expectations. *"I want to do X, here's some code"* is not an explanation of a problem.

Comment: Is this a web application?

Comment: I will try to explain better, when a user selects an item in the dropdownlist I will receive the selected value, and when the selected item has a value of "3" inside the sql server I want it to take the value line "31", I tried an IF cod_distrito = 3 then cod_distrito = 31 but  don't work

Comment: @Mary yeah is it

Answer (score 0):

Let's straighten out your data access code a bit. Database objects should be declared and disposed in the method where they are used. Using blocks take care of this for us even if there is an error.

You need to tell the `DropDownList` what field to display with the `.DataTextField` property. Why not just use a label above the `DropDownList` instead of inserting an item in the list that could be selected by mistake. I do not know what `Seg.usuario.cod_Distrito` is but it must be a `String` that matches an item in the list.

In the `SelectIndexChanged` event, I used `.Trim` just in case a space that we couldn't see is present. I displayed the result in a text box but you can use it anyway you wish.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillDropDownList()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillDropDownList()
    Dim Sql = " select  cod_distrito, no_distrito from tb_distrito where  cod_distrito<>0  and cod_distrito <= 25 order by no_distrito  "
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, New SqlConnection(ConStr))
        Cmd.Connection.Open()
        dt.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "cod_distrito"
    DropDownList1.DataBind()
    'DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Selecione uma Gerência Regional")
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Seg.usuario.cod_Distrito
End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Trim = "3" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "31"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, i gonna try to do this and i come back here to say what has changed